# Python version for the development

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I would like to do some development with Python that I don't use for a while and this is always confusing about the versions. It's just one project, so, I would like to stick with Python 3 and use for everything from now on. As Mac OS come with default Python 2.7, I had to install using the brew.

```
$ brew install python3
```

Later, I export the PATH in the `~/.bash_profile` using the command,

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH 
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I can see the Python version 3 from the terminal,

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.2

$ pip --version
pip 19.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

As I mentioned, I would like to stick with Python 3 for any kind of development works. My question is is the Python 3 default is set for the Mac OS and will be used for the project without the need for `virtualenv` setup?

Comment: [why-python-devs-should-use-pipenv](https://opensource.com/article/18/2/why-python-devs-should-use-pipenv)

Comment: you should __really__ use a virtualenv (whether `virtualenv` or `pipenv` or whatever doesn't matter) for development. It's the only sane way not only to keep your env stable, but also to make sure it can be rebuild from scratch etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `default` you mean the version of Python that is launched when you execute `python` on the terminal - you can check that with a `which` command

```
which python
```

And then see the version of the above output with a `--version` flag

If you want to set Python3 as the default (by default, I mean what I said above)  - you can use an `alias`

```
alias python=/path/to/your/python3
```

Comment: I exported the version 3 and set the alias, 

`export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH`
`alias python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`

Do you think the Python 3 is set as default for the development?

Comment: Should be, yes. When you say `default` - I am assuming you want `python myscript.py` to be run using `python3`. That is what should happen. To confirm, type `python` in your terminal. Once in the python prompt - see the version using `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: `>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:16:38) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because Python 3 is not compatible with Python 2, you should treat them as separate run-time systems. This is made easier because Python 2 installs the command `python2`, Python 3 installs the command `python3`.

So you should use the command `python2` for Python 2, and the command `python3` for Python 3, and avoid the command `python` because it is too ambiguous.

```
python3 --version
python3 -m pip --version
```